# Unable to break out of two Do loops

Tags: differential-equations

I wrote a mathematica program to solve one dimensional schrodinger equation for particle in box model with zero potential. I used two do loops to achieve the task. The inner do loop will solve schrodinger equation using NDSolve command three time at three closely spaced trial eigen values to find next trial eigen values using Newton Raphson method. The outer loop will repeat the interation
till the eigen value converges to within pre-defined energy threshold. In this outer loop I used break command along with If command to exit the loop if the
iteration satisfies pre-defined convergence condition. Unfortunately, Break command did not obey the condition when running the program and the program
actually ends after completing all the loop cycles specified. I want to know why it is like this? I attch the program here and the  output

```
ee = 19; Δx = 0.01; 
Do[ 
 Do[
  e[1] = ee - 0.01; 
  e[2] = ee; 
  e[3] = ee + 0.01;
  s = NDSolve[{ψ''[x] + 2 e[i] ψ[x] == 0, ψ[0] == 
      0, ψ'[0] == 1}, ψ, {x, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 15];
  b = Table[Evaluate[ψ[x] /. s], {x, 0, 1, 0.01}]; 
  ψf[i] = b[[101]], 
  {i, 3}
 ];
 e[2] = e[2] + (ψf[2]/((ψf[1] - ψf[3])/Δx)); 
 Print["   ", ee, "    ", Abs[e[2] - ee]]; 
 If[Abs[ee - e[2]] < 10^-5, Break[]]; 
 ee = e[2], 
 {20}
];
```

1 19    {0.360827}

2 {19.3608}    {0.186689}

3 {19.5475}    {0.0951768}

4 {19.6427}    {0.0480843}

5 {19.6908}    {0.024172}

6 {19.7149}    {0.0121186}

7 {19.7271}    {0.00606784}

8 {19.7331}    {0.00303595}

9 {19.7362}    {0.0015185}

10 {19.7377}    {0.000759438}

11 {19.7384}    {0.000379687}

12 {19.7388}    {0.000189853}

13 {19.739}    {0.0000949293}

14 {19.7391}    {0.0000474655}

15 {19.7392}    {0.0000237331}

16 {19.7392}    {0.0000118667}

17 {19.7392}    {5.93338*10^-6}

18 {19.7392}    {2.96671*10^-6}

19 {19.7392}    {1.48337*10^-6}

20 {19.7392}    {7.41688*10^-7}

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

The value of `Abs[ee - e[2]]` at each step is not a number but a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) containing a number.  Your condition `Abs[ee - e[2]] < 10^-5` is therefore never `True`, and `Break[]` is never evaluated.  The problem is solved by simply adding [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html) to make that line:

```
If[First[Abs[ee - e[2]]] < 10^-5, Break[]];
```

Comment: This work fine and I tested it. Thanks